# Example of a Solr plugin written in Clojure

Tags: clojure, solr

have anyone seen a Solr plugin example written in Clojure?

I guess it should be straight forward, but I would appreciate a simple example before I started working on one specific plugin. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is something at github: [lsa4solr](http://github.com/algoriffic/lsa4solr).

Comment: Yea, I know of that one, but it's a rather complex one. Anyway, it should be straight forward so I should stop asking and start coding :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You also have the following Solr Clojure clients:

- [Flux](https://github.com/mwmitchell/flux) *(Last updated in 2015)*

  - Supports Apache Solr 4.9 *(latest Apache Solr version is 5.1)*
- [Solrclj](https://github.com/mlehman/solrclj) *(Last updated in 2013)*
- github.com/mattdeboard/Icarus *(Last updated in 2012)*
- github.com/mikejs/clojure-solr *(Last updated in 2010)*
- github.com/algoriffic/lsa4solr *(Last updated in 2010)*

Comment: As of 2019 [corona clojure solr wrapper](https://github.com/Stylitics/corona) is the way to go. Though no plugin in clojure as such.